# Error de suma productos

Tags: php, html, css

estoy realizando un carrito de compra en php, y a la hora de sumar los productos, no suma las líneas del mismo producto, es decir, si por ejemplo, añado dos libretas, pues me aparecen dos libretas en lugar de una, el precio final total lo hace bien, sin embargo no es lo que quería conseguir del todo ¿hay alguna forma de evitar que me añada esto?, es decir, que si ve que el producto ya existe, pues que deje de añadirme o repetirme el mismo producto sino que se vaya sumando al precio en función de la cantidad que tenga. Adjunto el código:

```html
<?php
    //INICIO DE LA PÁGINA
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tienda</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/site.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Architects+Daughter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<!--FORMULARIO DE LOS PRODUCTOS A VENDER-->
    <h1 class="font-italic">¡Bienvenido!</h1>
    <form id="inicio" method="post" action="carrito.php">
        <p>Selecciona el producto que quieres comprar:</p>
        <select name="articulo">
            <option value="Libreta">Libreta</option>
            <option value="Boligrafo">Boligrafo</option>
            <option value="Grapadora">Grapadora</option>
            <option value="Tijera">Tijera</option>
            <option value="Carpeta">Carpeta</option>
            <option value="Cartulina">Cartulina</option>
            <option value="Estuche">Estuche</option>
            <option value="Mochila">Mochila</option>
            <option value="Rotulador">Rotulador</option>
            <option value="Goma">Goma</option>
            <option value="Fichero">Fichero</option>
        </select>
        <p>
            <label for="nombre">¿Cuantos quiere comprar?</label>
            <br />
            <input type="number" name="number" id="number" size="15" max="10" min="1" value="0">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Añadir al carrito" class="btn btn-success" role="button">
            <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='http://localhost/dashboard/';" class="btn btn-danger" value="Salir"/>
        </p>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<?php
//ERROR: NO SUMA LAS LINEAS DEL MISMO PRODUCTO, LAS DIVIDE EN LINEAS DE UNA UNIDAD

//INICIAMOS LA SESIÓN
session_start();
   if(!isset($_SESSION["carrito"]))
    {
        $_SESSION["carrito"]=[];
    }
    if(!isset($_POST["number"]))
    {
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<p class='alertaError bg-warning Width 25% text-center'>ERROR: HAS ACCEDIDO A CARRITO DIRECTAMENTE</p>"; 
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<p class='alertaError bg-warning Width 25% text-center'>Seras reedirigido de nuevo a inicio</p>"; 
        header('Refresh: 3; URL=inicio.php');
    }
    else
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < $_POST["number"]; $i++)
        {
            array_push($_SESSION["carrito"], $_POST["articulo"]);
        }
    
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Carrito</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/site.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Architects+Daughter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="rounded border border-dark text-center">
        <?php
        //ASIGNAMOS ARRAY DE LOS PRECIOS Y TOTAL
        $precios = [1.50, 0.50, 3.00, 0.90, 0.20, 0.10, 5.50, 10.00, 0.20, 0.05, 2.00];
        $total = 0;
        echo "<img src='assets/img/carrito.png' class='imagen_Carrito'/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<p class='carritoTexto rounded border border-dark text-center bg-secondary'>TU CARRITO<p>";
        //SI EL CARRITO ESTA VACIO
        if(empty($_SESSION["carrito"]))
        {
            echo "<p class='cestaVacia bg-danger w-25 text-center' bg-danger>Su cesta está vacía</p>";
        }
        //SI NO ESTA VACIO
        else
        {
            //AVERIGUAMOS QUE COMPRA RECORRIENDO EL ARRAY DE CARRITO CON SUS ARTICULOS
            for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION["carrito"]); $i++)
            {   
                echo "<tr class='rounded border border-dark text-center'> <td class='bg-primary border border-dark text-center'>Articulo " . ($i + 1) . "</td><td class='bg-warning'>";
                echo $_SESSION["carrito"][$i] . "</td>";

                //SEGÚN LOS CASOS, ES UN PRODUCTO U OTRO
                switch($_SESSION["carrito"][$i])
                {
                    case "Libreta":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark border border-dark text-center'>" . $precios[0] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/libreta.jpg'/></td>";
                    $total += $precios[0];
                    break;

                    case "Boligrafo":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark border border-dark text-center'>" . $precios[1] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/boligrafo.jpg'/></td>";                   
                    $total += $precios[1];
                    break;

                    case "Grapadora":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark border border-dark text-center'>" . $precios[2] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/grapadora.jpg'/></td>";                    
                    $total += $precios[2];
                    break;

                    case "Tijera":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark border border-dark text-center'>" . $precios[3] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/tijera.jpg'/></td>"; 
                    $total += $precios[3];
                    break;

                    case "Carpeta":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark border border-dark text-center'>" . $precios[4] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/carpeta.jpg'/></td>"; 
                    $total += $precios[4];
                    break;

                    case "Cartulina":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark border border-dark text-center'>" . $precios[5] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/cartulina.jpg'/></td>"; 
                    $total += $precios[5];
                    break;

                    case "Estuche":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark border border-dark text-center'>" . $precios[6] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/estuche.jpg'/></td>";
                    $total += $precios[6];
                    break;

                    
                    case "Mochila":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark border border-dark text-center'>" . $precios[7] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/mochila.jpg'/></td>";
                    $total += $precios[7];
                    break;

                
                    case "Rotulador":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark border border-dark text-center'>" . $precios[8] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/rotulador.jpg'/></td>";
                    $total += $precios[8];
                    break;

                    case "Goma":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark border border-dark text-center'>" . $precios[9] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/goma.jpg'/></td>";
                    $total += $precios[9];
                    break;
    
                        
                    case "Fichero":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark border border-dark text-center'>" . $precios[10] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/fichero.jpg'/></td>";
                    $total += $precios[10];
                    break;

                }
                
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
        ?>
        </table>

        <br/>
        <div class="total bg-white text-center w-25 border border-dark">
            Total: <?php echo $total . "€"; ?>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <form action="pedidos.php" method="POST">
            <input type="button" value="Seguir comprando" onclick="location.href='inicio.php'"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="total" value=<?php echo "$total"?> />
            <input type="submit" value="Gestionar pedido" name="gestionar" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: deberias de agrupar el array, crear un listado con un objeto que tenga una propiedad con el total y otra con los items agrupados. En esta pagina me he encontrado un ejemplo de como hacerlo.
https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/762/how-to-group-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-key-in-php

Comment: Vas metiendo los productos que se añaden al carrito en un array. Si se elige el producto X, pues se añade al array un elemento representando ese producto. Que se elige otra vez el producto X, pues se añade al array otro elemento representando ese producto. Y, claro, luego te salen repetidos. ¿Qué tal si usases el concepto cantidad? Cada elemento del carrito debería representar un producto y saber cúanta cantidad se pide del mismo.